# Loading JSON data to Array and fetching the values in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to put the JSON data into an array and fetch the data

```
{
```

"data":{
      "platform":{
         "id":"d0feb170-76ed-77e9-a24f-44c49397cb8f",
         "version":0,
         "updatedTime":1557910234867,
         "dataVersion":{
            "version":0,
            "updatedTime":1557910234867
         }
      },
    "machine":{
         "version":44,
         "updatedTime":1557910026619,
         "version":{
            "version":19,
            "updatedTime":1557910026619
         },
         "systemId":"Machine1",
         "activeStatus":"true",
         "**settings**":[
            {
               "protNumber":"1.2",
               "proto":"TestHead2^^Adult^^Head",
               "id":"21a8fbb8-40ea-4868-ae3a-ee1d130eb01b",
               "name":"TestHead2",
               "humanoid":"Adult",
               "anatomy":"Head",
               "lastUpdated":"Wed, 15 May 2019 08:47:06 GMT",
               "version":0
            },
    {
               "protNumber":"1.8",
               "proto":"TestHead8^^Adult^^Head",
               "id":"2a25874e-cb9f-40c1-93db-a0859b209491",
               "name":"TestHead8",
               "humanoid":"Adult",
               "anatomy":"Head",
               "lastUpdated":"Wed, 15 May 2019 08:47:06 GMT",
               "version":0
            },
            {
               "protNumber":"1.88",
               "proto":"TestHead88^^Adult^^Head",
               "id":"50cc13d8-6d43-4fcd-9d60-08ce4f97632d",
               "name":"TestHead88",
               "humanoid":"Adult",
               "anatomy":"Head",
               "lastUpdated":"Wed, 15 May 2019 08:47:06 GMT",
               "version":0
            }
         ],
         "deviceDeviation":{
            "new":9,
            "deviated":0,
            "newMatched":0,
            "totalProtocols":3
         }
      }
   },
   "success":true,
   "statusCode":200,
   "errorMessage":""
}

How can I put the data in the **settings** into an Array and fetch them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to fetch data:-

Below, I have created one JSON extractor config for protNumber. 
[image]

Please check the variable in the results. You can use the first three variables or if you need all then use the 4th...depend on your requirement. Fetch using ${prNumVar_1},${prNumVar_2} etc
[image]
Create multiple extractor for different variables..like prot, id, name as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.